# Converting MKPolygon Objective-C code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, mkmapview, mkpolygon

I have the following Objective-C method:

```
- (void)addPolygonToMap {
    NSInteger numberOfPoints = [self.coordinates count];
    
    if (numberOfPoints > 4) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D points[numberOfPoints];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
            points[i] = [self.coordinates[i] MKCoordinateValue];
        }
        
        self.polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:numberOfPoints];
        [self.mapView addOverlay: self.polygon];
    }
    
    self.isDrawingPolygon = NO;
    [self.drawPolygonButton setTitle:@"draw" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.canvasView.image = nil;
    [self.canvasView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

My attempt at converting it to Swift:

```
func addPolygonToMap() {
    var numberOfPoints: NSInteger = self.coordinates.count
    
    if (numberOfPoints > 4) {
        var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        var coordsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.alloc(numberOfPoints)

        for i in 0..<numberOfPoints {
            points.append(coordsPointer[i])
        }
        
        self.polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: numberOfPoints)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(self.polygon)
        
        coordsPointer.dealloc(numberOfPoints)
    }
    
    self.isDrawingPolygon = false
    self.drawPolygonButton.setTitle("Draw", forState: .Normal)
    self.canvasView.image = nil
    self.canvasView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Finally, when the delegate method is called it's not actually adding the `overlay` to the `mapView`. I can't see anything.

I'm assuming it's my `self.addPolytonToMap()` method, but I'm not 100% sure. The whole scenario works fine in my Objective-C project.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if (overlay is MKPolygon) {
        var overlayPathView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        overlayPathView.fillColor = UIColor.cyanColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        overlayPathView.strokeColor = UIColor.cyanColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        overlayPathView.lineWidth = 5
        
        return overlayPathView
    } else if (overlay is MKPolyline) {
        var overlayPathView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        overlayPathView.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
        overlayPathView.lineWidth = 5
        
        return overlayPathView
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that in my Objective-C version, the `points[i].latitude` are coming through okay, however when I do the following I get a strange output:

`println(coordsPointer[i].latitude)`

**Output:**

> 1.63041663127611e-321
>
> 1.64523860065135e-321
>
> 1.65511991356818e-321
>
> 1.68970450877706e-321
>
> 1.7045264781523e-321
>
> 1.72922976044436e-321

This would explain why I don't see the `overlay`, however my experience with `UnsafeMutablePointer<>` is limited.

Comment: i just swiflty browsed your code - you seem to be allocating coordsPointer and never fill it. But then you set points from coords pointer ... but you actually should have to read the values from self.coordinates[i]

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by modifying the `addPolygonToMap()` method:

```
func addPolygonToMap() {
    var numberOfPoints: NSInteger = self.coordinates.count

    if (numberOfPoints > 4) {
        var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

        for i in 0..<numberOfPoints {
            points.insert(self.coordinates[i].MKCoordinateValue, atIndex: i)
        }

        self.polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: numberOfPoints)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(self.polygon)
    }

    self.isDrawingPolygon = false
    self.drawPolygonButton.setTitle("Draw", forState: .Normal)
    self.canvasView.image = nil
    self.canvasView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Thanks to **@Volker** for the help.